# Any idea how to concatenate javascripts, so that the second script will update some values that expands from the first script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set some default values for a web widget from Bizzabo, like this:

```
<div class="bizzabo-sections-widget" data-unique-name="301765" data-tab-id="1749054" data-internal-website-base-url="https://events.bizzabo.com/301765"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    !function() {
        var e = document.createElement("script");
        window.bz_widget_env = "https://events.bizzabo.com", e.type = "text/javascript", e.async = !0, e.src = "https://organizer.bizzabo.com/widgets/sections/sections.js";
        var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(e,t)}();
</script>
```

This script expands into a form, with the following input:

```
<input type="text" name="localValues" class="form-control" title="input First Name">
<input type="text" name="localValues" class="form-control" title="input Last Name">
<input type="text" name="localValues" class="form-control" title="input Email Address" data-system-type="primary-email">
```

---

Now I would like to set the above 3 inputs with default value using JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("input[type='text'][name='localValues'][title='input First Name']").val("Happy").change();
$("input[type='text'][name='localValues'][title='input Last Name']").val("Fellow").change();
$("input[type='text'][name='localValues'][title='input Email Address']").val("Tester1@xxxyyy.com").change();
});
</script>
```

---

But this does not work. The second jquery script works with the `<input>` directly, but not when they are expanded from the first script.

My question: is there a work around to make it work, such as jQuery(document).ready(function($) is not an page ready event, but when the first script getting loaded event?

How to put, concatenate the second script upon first script. Is that possible?

Comment: Put your 2nd script in a function  `function second_script() { ... }` then call it from 1st  `second_script();`

Comment: not working. remember the first script is a third party widget that we have zero control. 
<script type="text/javascript">
    !function() {
        var e = document.createElement("script");
        window.bz_widget_env = "https://events.bizzabo.com", e.type = "text/javascript", e.async = !0, e.src = "https://organizer.bizzabo.com/widgets/sections/sections.js";
        var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(e,t)}();
</script>

I can insert a function in that block, but there is no effect. Do I miss something?